# Diagonal convergence and Uniform Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

The following problem was in a supplement to Rudin's "*Principles of Mathematical Analysis*"

> Let $\{f_n\}_{n \in Z_+}$ be a sequence of *complex valued* and *continuous* functions on a *compact metric space* $(K, d)$ and suppose that it *converges pointwise* to a *continuous limit function* $f$. Now let $p$ be any limit point of $K$, if for every sequence $\{x_n\}_{n \in Z_+} \subseteq K$ that converges to $p$, $f_n(x_n)$ converges to $f(p)$, then $f_n$ converges uniformly on $K$.

**My Problem**

I have tried to prove this statement without success so far. Therefore I turned to the site in order to find clues on how to proceed. However, I noticed a **possibly incorrect** trend in the answers to similar questions, namely:

"*We shall proceed by contradiction. Suppose that $f_n$ does not converge uniformly on $K$, then, by the negation of the definition:
$$(\exists M > 0): (\forall n \in Z_+, \exists x_n \in K: |f(x_n) - f_{n}(x_n)| \geq M)$$
and the proof follows easily for there is a convergent subsequence $x_{k_n} \rightarrow p$ of $x_n$ (here the construction of the sequence itself is subtended) and $f_{k_{n}}(x_{k_n}) \rightarrow f(p)$*"

However, **an incorrect negation of the definition of uniform convergence** is used in such proofs. Recall that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $K$ if and only if:
$$(\forall \epsilon > 0), (\exists N \in Z_+: \forall x \in K, \forall n \geq N, |f(x) - f_{n}(x)| < \epsilon)$$

therefore the **correct negation of the definition of uniform convergence** is:

$$(\exists M > 0): (\forall N \in Z_+, \exists x_N \in K \text{ and } \exists n_N \geq N: |f(x_N) - f_{n_N}(x_N)| \geq M)$$

For example, let $N=2$, then, if we subtend the construction of the sequences $\{x_N\}$ and $\{n_N\}$, we could have $n_N$ = 1000 and hence $|f(x_2) - f_{1000}(x_2)| \geq M$ insted of $|f(x_2) - f_{2}(x_2)| \geq M$. Moreover, I do not see an easy way to to extend $\{x_N\}$ so that there is correspondence with $\{n_N\}$ for when we extract the subsequence we need to be sure that there are infinitely many elements of the subsequence satisfying the negation above.

**My Question**

Now, I am not completely sure that what I have written is completely right, therefore I leave to anyone to prove me wrong. Furthermore, I would like to know how can the statement be proved.

---

As always, any comment or answer is welcome and let me know if I can explain myself clearer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suspicions are correct, that negation is slightly incorrect, but it may not actually affect the rest of a proof that someone gave, I don't know.

Since uniform convergence says "eventually you are close in the supremum norm", the negation says "infinitely often you are not close in the supremum norm". i.e. The correct negation gives you a "bad" $M > 0$ for which it is the case that for infinitely many $n$ we have $\sup_{x \in K}|f(x) - f_n(x)| \geq M$. Then to unwind 'infinitely many' you say something like you have said: For every $N  \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists a later $n_N > N$ such that....

I suppose since $K$ is compact you can now get a convergent subsequence of the $x_{n_N}$ to a limit point $p$ and then...

Comment: Actually I do not think that you can escape the difference between $x_N$ and $n_N$. For example. in your case we would start by denoting by $x_1$ the point of $K$ such that $|f(x_{1}) - f_{n_1}(x_{1})| \geq M$ but once again you have that $1$ is not necessarily $n_1$, and so on ...

Comment: I think I get what you're saying but I also think you are overthinking something. Perhaps you want to "fill in" the sequence by taking $y_1 = x_1,\ y_2 = x_1,\ y_3 = x_1,\dots,\ y_{n_1} = x_1, $ and then $y_{n_1+1} = x_2$ etc.?

Comment: Now I see your point! Thank you very much, I thought about filling the sequence somehow but it didn’t occur me to do it in this way (which is actually simpler and more effective). Also, could you explain to me when the continuity of the single functions of the sequence is used in the proof? (For I have only seen the continuity of the limit function being used)

Comment: @T_M: Why do we need to take a subsequence of $x_{n_N}$? We have $x_n \to p$ by assumption, so every subsequence of $(x_n)$ also converges to $p$, right?

Comment: @T_M: Ah, nevermind. I see now that we do not have $x_n \to p$ by assumption...