# Diagonal convergence on a compact set implies uniform convergence (Proof verification)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence

My question comes from exercise 25.15(a) in *Elementary Analysis* 2nd ed by Ross (and is closely related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4504812/diagonal-convergence-and-uniform-convergence)):

> **25.15**. *Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of continuous functions on $[a,b]$.*
>
> (a) *Suppose that, for each $x$ in $[a,b]$, $(f_n(x))$ is a decreasing sequence of real numbers. Prove that if $f_n \to 0$ pointwise on $[a,b]$, then $f_n \to 0$ uniformly on $[a,b]$. Hint: If not, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ and a sequence $(x_n)$ in $[a,b]$ such that $f_n(x_n) \geq \epsilon$ for all $n$. Obtain a contradiction.*

The hint gave me pause; it does not appear to be the precise negation of the statement of uniform continuity. If $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $[a,b]$, this means:
\begin{align*}
    (\forall \epsilon > 0) (\exists k \in \mathbb{N}) (\forall n \geq k) (\forall x \in [a,b]) (|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon). 
\end{align*}

Then I believe the negation should read
\begin{align*}
    (\exists \epsilon > 0) (\forall k \in \mathbb{N}) (\exists n_k \geq k) (\exists x_k \in [a,b]) (|f_{n_k}(x_{n_k}) - f(x_{n_k})| \geq \epsilon), 
\end{align*}

or in more comprehensible language: there exists an $\epsilon > 0$, a subsequence $(f_{n_k})_{k=1}^{\infty}$, and a corresponding sequence $(x_{n_k})_{k=1}^{\infty}$ in $E$, such that $|f_{n_k}(x_{n_k}) - f(x_{n_k})| \geq \epsilon$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

**My first question is: Have I correctly negated the definition of uniform continuity?**

If my negation is indeed correct, then the author appears to be implicitly using the following nontrivial result:

**Proposition.** *Let $E$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$, let $f$ and $(f_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be continuous real-valued functions on $E$, and suppose $f_n \to f$ pointwise. Suppose also that $(f_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges "diagonally" to $f$ in the following sense: For any sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $E$ that converges to some $x \in E$, we have  $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f_n(x_n) = f(x)$. Then $f_n \to f$ uniformly.*

As an exercise, I've attempted to prove it. **My second question is: Is the following proof correct?**

*Proof*: We proceed by contradiction. Suppose $f_n \to f$ pointwise and diagonally, but not uniformly. Then there exists an $\epsilon > 0$, a subsequence $(f_{n_k})_{k=1}^{\infty}$, and a corresponding sequence $(x_{n_k})_{k=1}^{\infty}$ in $E$, such that $|f_{n_k}(x_{n_k}) - f(x_{n_k})| \geq \epsilon$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $E$ is compact, $(x_{n_k})_{k=1}^{\infty}$ has a subsequence $(x_{m_j})_{j=1}^{\infty}$ which converges to a point $x \in E$. Then we have
\begin{align*}
    \hspace{2cm} |f_{m_j}(x_{m_j}) - f(x_{m_j})|  \geq \epsilon \quad \forall j.  \hspace{2cm} (*) 
\end{align*}

Also, $\lim\limits_{j \to \infty} f(x_{m_j}) = f(x)$ by the continuity of $f$, and $\lim\limits_{j \to \infty} f_{m_j}(x_{m_j}) = f(x)$ by diagonal convergence. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
    |f_{m_j}(x_{m_j}) - f(x_{m_j})| \leq |f_{m_j}(x_{m_j}) - f(x)| + |f(x) - f(x_{m_j})| \to 0 \quad \text{ as } j \to \infty. 
\end{align*}

Consequently, $\lim\limits_{j \to \infty} |f_{m_j}(x_{m_j}) - f(x_{m_j})| = 0$, which contradicts $(*)$. So the convergence must be uniform.

Any isues with the proof, or suggestions for improvement?

Comment: Actually in your specific context, where your function is decreasing to $0$, once you have the divergence on a subsequence, you have it for the original sequence as well.

Comment: However, the proof looks good, its a nifty result.  And yes, you did do the negation correctly, though I think the hint just wants you to take the extra step of using that the sequence is decreasing pointwise, so $f_k(x)\geq f_{n_k}(x)$, since for a subsequence you can assume $n_k\geq k$.